# Why would a foreach loop stop after the first iteration on a mysqli result object?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, nested

I have a set of mysqli results that I am iterating through to create nested arrays with all the same order ids in each nested array.

[Here is what each record looks like when using `<pre>print_r($result)</pre>`](http://pastebin.com/FnN9zftT).

mysqli select:

```
SELECT s.*, s.id as stopId, o.* FROM stops AS s INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.id = s.orderId WHERE o.status = 'A' AND scheduledArrivalEarly >= CURDATE() ORDER BY scheduledArrivalEarly ASC, state ASC
```

Here is the mysqli result object:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 83
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 478
    [type] => 0
)
```

I know that I have more than one result, and the problem I'm having is when I iterate through the result object and start constructing the array, It only goes through 1 iteration and stops.

[Here is the array structure I expect when using my code to build the nested arrays](http://pastebin.com/t8RCMjRa).

I am getting the first result with that structure, but like I stated before, the iteration stops after the first result.

Here is the code I'm using to construct the nested arrays:

```
$ress = $results;
$count = 0;
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $count . "<br>";
    $orderId = $result['orderId'];
    $records[$count] = array();
    foreach($ress as $r){
        if($r['orderId'] == $orderId and !in_array($r, $records[$count])){
            array_push($records[$count], $r);
        }
    }
    $count += 1;
}
```

Does anybody know why this would stop after the first iteration?

Comment: Please, add the request code too (SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a result set isn't an array (though it is iterable), it's a resource. However, when you get to the end of a result set, you need to manually reset it to the beginning before iterating over it again

After the first retrieval to `$result`, you're iterating over the entirety of `$ress` (less the first record), so you need to reset the resultset pointer to be able to get to the next `$result`, because both $ress and $results are pointing to the same resource.

Use [data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to reset the resultset back to `$count` immediately after `$count += 1;`

```
$ress = $results;
$count = 0;
foreach($results as $result){
    echo $count . "<br>";
    $orderId = $result['orderId'];
    $records[$count] = array();
    foreach($ress as $r){
        if($r['orderId'] == $orderId and !in_array($r, $records[$count])){
            array_push($records[$count], $r);
        }
    }
    $count += 1;
    $results->data_seek($count);
}
```

Comment: This was it!  I didn't realize that I had to reset the pointer.  Thanks!

Comment: this is still very ugly. fetch the records first to an array, then you'll no more problems with the looping.